# TeX Live installation: specify just the scheme on the command line?

Tags: texlive, installing

I'm trying to make a bash script to install TeX Live on CentOS (as part of provisioning in Vagrant). I want `scheme=small` but don't need any other options (I'll run `tlmgr install` to add a few more things after that). Is there a way to do that in the script without having a separate profile file? I expected to be able to do something like `install-tl -scheme small -batch` (pseudo-code - I know there is no batch flag), but all the docs seem to expect you do either have a profile file or do the installation interactively.

Or if I *must* have a profile file, what is the minimum content to just specify the scheme? I need to build the file in the shell script, so simple is best, but all the docs tell me to start with the `texlive.profile` file that is created when an install is done - that's a lot of stuff, most of which I don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

By experimentation, I discovered that a profile file with just the scheme is enough to satisfy the installer. So this works fine:

```sh
echo 'selected_scheme scheme-small' > temp.profile
./install-tl -profile temp.profile
```

If someone would like to see the context, this is my whole script (I know this is not a Linux forum, but someone else may be wanting to automate their TeX Live installation):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

# An error exit function
function error_exit
{
    echo "$1" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

# Download and unpack the latest TeX Live tarball
wget -q http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz || error_exit "Failure getting texlive tarball"
tar -xzf install-tl-unx.tar.gz || error_exit "Failure unpacking texlive tarball"
rm -f install-tl-unx.tar.gz

# Install with the small scheme
cd install-tl-20* || error_exit "Failure changing to texlive install directory"
echo 'selected_scheme scheme-small' > temp.profile
./install-tl -profile temp.profile || error_exit "Failure installing texlive core"
rm -f temp.profile

# Add the bin directory to the path
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

# Install additional packages
tlmgr install collection-langjapanese || error_exit "Failure installing collection-langjapanese"
tlmgr install textpos || error_exit "Failure installing textpos"
tlmgr install hanging || error_exit "Failure installing hanging"
tlmgr install ulem || error_exit "Failure installing ulem"
tlmgr install needspace || error_exit "Failure installing needspace"
tlmgr install ec || error_exit "Failure installing ec"
```

Comment: And bashrc might only be good if all you ever use is the command line (or if it is sourced from the profile).

Comment: Actually, my normal use of the TeX-related commands is from PHP code, so I can spell out the whole path anyway. I set the path in `.bashrc` just for quick tests I might do on the command line.