# How to install tlmgr and texliveonfly in Amazon linux machine / CentOS?

Tags: texlive, installing, linux, ctan, tlmgr

I want to install full latex on my AWS environment which uses Amazon machine image. They provide only texlive-2012 which not upto date. 
With tlmgr and texliveonfly I can install the missing packages on the fly.

Can anyone tell me how to install tlmgr and texliveonfly on amazon machine image, which is similar to CentOs.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the official installation script `install-tl` provided by TeX Live. Uninstall the previously installed (outdated) version and then install the most recent version. You can use `tlmgr` to install missing packages like `texliveonfly` if you like.

You can have a look at

- [How to build my LaTeX automatically with pdflatex using Travis CI?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398830/how-to-build-my-latex-automatically-with-pdflatex-using-travis-ci/398831#398831)
- [TeX Live installation: specify just the scheme on the command line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342612/tex-live-installation-specify-just-the-scheme-on-the-command-line/342799#342799)

for example to see how others used `install-tl` to install the most recent version of TeX Live.